# How can solve CI_DB_mysql_result

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Hello everybody i have problem with my page i have controller name user and i need get value from my function and used it in another function but i have problem :

Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string

Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php

Line Number: **

my code in controller:

```
function view_ind()
{
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $data['user']=$this->user_model->get_name($username);
    $place=$this->user_model->get_place($username);
    $data['results']=$this->user_model->get_all_names_info($place);     
    $data['main_content']='view_page';
    $this->load->view('include/tem',$data);     

}
```

and in my models :

```
    function get_place($user)
{
    $this->db->select('place');
    $this->db->where('username',$user)->from('users');
    return  $this->db->get();

}
```

and

```
    function get_all_names_info($place)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('personal_info');
    $this->db->where('place =',$place);

    return $this->db->get();
}
```

when need using $place show error message and $place not define .. i hope solve my problem soon ... thank you

Comment: can you show an array for $place which you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you function into

```
  function get_place($user)
{
    $this->db->select('place');
    $this->db->where('username',$user)->from('users');
    return  $this->db->get();

}
```

to

```
function get_place($user)
{

    return $this->db->get_where('user', array('username'=>$user))->row()->place;
}
```